# Okay... but what does "second-countable" actually mean?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition, second-countable

1. A topology is a pair of sets $(X,\tau)$ such that

   - $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$.
   - $X,\emptyset \in \tau$.
   - $\forall S\subseteq\tau.\bigcup S \in \tau$
   - $\forall A,B\in \tau.A \cap B \in \tau$
2. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the topology $\tau$, then
   $$\tau=\left\{\bigcup S:S\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{B})\right\}$$
   ($\tau$ is generated by the union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$)
3. $\{(a,b)\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R}):a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ is a base for the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{R}$
4. $\Bbb{Q}\ne\Bbb{R}$

These four statements *cannot* be true simultaneously, but every explanation of "second-countable" that I have been offered - taken at as stated - translates directly into these four propositions (aside from the fact that I am using $\Bbb{R}$ as an example, but you get my point).

So either I have discovered an error in the foundations of general topology that somehow eluded mathematicians for ~100 years, or the McTextbook explanation of second-countable spaces uses the words "is," "same," "the," and "base" incorrectly.

I choose to believe the latter. So if "second-countable" doesn't mean what Wikipedia says it means, what does it mean?

**Edit**

The reason why these statements cannot be simultaneously true is a simple matter of substitution.

The equational definition of the Euclidean topology "the union of open balls" is:

$$E=\langle \{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb{R}\}\rangle=\left\{\bigcup S:S\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb{R}\}})\right\}$$

This is acheived by substituting "the set of open intervals" for $\mathcal{B}$ in expression 2.

If $\Bbb{Q}\ne\Bbb{R}$, then

$$\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb{R}\}\ne\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$$

Therefore,

$$E\ne\langle\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb{R}\}\rangle$$

Comment: Those four statements **are** all true simulaneously. Why do you think that they cannot be?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Edited

Comment: Prove your claim by demonstrating a contradiction from those four statements.

Comment: @WilliamElliot See edit.

Comment: The implication $X\neq Y\implies \bigcup \{A:A\subset X\}\neq\bigcup \{A:A\subset Y\}$ is false.

Comment: Indeed.  The two bases are different, one countable, the other uncountable.  So what?  They both generate the same topology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> either I have discovered an error in the foundations of general topology that somehow eluded mathematicians for ~100 years, or the McTextbook explanation of second-countable spaces uses the words "is," "same," "the," and "base" incorrectly.

Or, your argument is flawed.

Your claim beginning "Therefore" is **incorrect**: in general, just because $\mathbb{A}\not=\mathbb{B}$ we **cannot** conclude that $$\{\bigcup S: S\subseteq\mathbb{A}\}\not=\{\bigcup T: T\subseteq\mathbb{B}\}.$$ It's possible that two different collections of sets have the same "set of unions."

The second-countability of $\mathbb{R}$ provides such an example, with $\mathbb{A}$ the set of open intervals with real endpoints and $\mathbb{B}$ the set of open intervals with rational endpoints. For a simpler example, take $\mathbb{A}$ to be the set of all one-element sets of natural numbers and take $\mathbb{B}$ to be the set of all finite sets of natural numbers.

---

The fact that the set of open intervals with real endpoints and the set of open intervals with rational endpoints generate the same topology is a consequence of the following:

> Every open interval with real endpoints is a union of open intervals with rational endpoints.

And this is easy to prove. Suppose $a<b$ are real numbers. Consider the set $$I=\bigcup_{p,q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (a,b), p<q}(p,q).$$ $I$ is a union of open intervals each of which is contained in $(a,b)$, so $I\subseteq (a,b)$. In the other direction, for each $x\in (a,b)$ we can find rationals $p,q$ with $a<p<x<q<b$; then $x\in (p,q)\subseteq I$. So in fact $I=(a,b)$.

- Here's another argument which may be easier to parse. Pick sequences of rationals $\alpha=(\alpha_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}},\beta=(\beta_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\alpha$ converging to $a$ from above, $\beta$ converging to $b$ from below, and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ always staying inside $(a,b)$. For example, if $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\pi$ we could take $\beta=(3,3.1,3.14,...)$ and $\alpha=(2, 1.5, 1.42, ...)$. Now show $$(a,b)=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(\alpha_i,\beta_i).$$

From this we can write any union of open intervals with real endpoints as a union of unions of open intervals with rational endpoints - and a union of unions is just a union.

---

As an interesting aside, note that it's *not* enough to just observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$; or more jargonily, there are **separable** (= countable dense set) spaces which are not second-countable.

The ones that occur to me offhand are pretty pathological beasties. I'll add a more natural example if I can think of one, but for the moment consider the following construction. Given an arbitrary topological space $(X,\tau)$ consider the space $(Y,\sigma)$ with

- $Y=X\sqcup\{*\}$, and
- $\sigma=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{U\cup\{*\}: U\in\tau\}$.

Basically, we take $(X,\tau)$, add a new "special" point, and glue that point to every other point in $X$. The space $(Y,\sigma)$ has a one-element dense subset, namely $\{*\}$, but if $(X,\tau)$ wasn't second-countable then $(Y,\sigma)$ won't be either. Some authors$^*$ call this the "[one-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) [katamarification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katamari_Damacy)" of a space.

*(By contrast, it's easy to show that second-countability does imply separability: just pick an element from each of the countable basic opens.)*

$^*$Specifically, me.

Comment: Certainly, but the topology generated by the countable base does not contain the open set $(-\pi,\pi)$, the one generated by the uncountable base does. They are *not* the same topology.

Comment: @R.Burton Yes, it does: $$(-\pi,\pi)=(-3,3)\cup(-3.1,3.1)\cup(-3.14,3.14)\cup ...$$ Your claim is incorrect.

Comment: Can you prove your claim?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Who, me or R. Burton?

Comment: Sorry I meant him, not you. Your comment appeared juat a split second before I pressed enter.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but I'll need a moment to run through the formal verification.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Imagine my relief... thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich :P

Comment: I noticed two things 1) proving this is *much* easier with limits than without, why does anyone ever want to do analysis without limits, WHY!? 2) my proof sketch$^2$ (that's a of a proof-sketch sketch that I've written on a napkin) that "every real number is the supremum or infimum of a set of rationals" relies on the assumption that the reals are totally ordered. Can you still do this if you remove the ordering relation on the reals?

Comment: @R.Burton If you don't have the ordering, what does supremum/infimum mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber supremum/infimum is just the steps I took to show that the every open interval is the union of a sequence of intervals with rational endpoints (implicit in $(-\pi,\pi)=(-3,3)\cup(-3.1,3.1)\cup(-3.14,3.14)\cup ...$). It might not be *necessary* to use the ordering relation to prove that the union of a subset of a countable base contains a member of the standard, uncountable base.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is to say, "if the reals weren't ordered as they are, would they still be [provably] second-countable?" This is the stepping stone my mind takes on the way to "what if a space was unorderable?"

Comment: @R.Burton "It might not be necessary to use the ordering relation to prove that the union of a subset of a countable base contains a member of the standard, uncountable base." Sure; for example, any metrizable space with a countable dense subset is second-countable, and $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) is indeed metrizable and has a countable dense subset. But not all metrizable spaces come from orderings.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the interval $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ in $\mathbb{R}$. There is a sequence $\lbrace x_i\rbrace=\lbrace1,1.4,1.41,1.414,...\rbrace$ of rational numbers which converges to $\sqrt{2}$ from below. The union of the intervals $(-x_i,x_i)$ is the interval ($-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.

To produce any interval $(x,y)$ for $x,y$ real, $x<y$ we can construct sequences of rationals $x_i,y_i$ where $x_i$ converges to $x$ from above and $y_i$ converges to $y$ from below. The union of the intervals $(x_i,y_i)$ will be the required interval. These intervals form a basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that while the end-points of these intervals are rational, they are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, not merely in $\mathbb{Q}$.